# Astah UML is it possible to generate a nested class diagram?

Tags: uml, astah

I'm learning Astah and I would like to reverse-engineer my project into a class diagram.

Let's say I got a folder structure like this

```
com/
|_ company/
|  |_ package1/
|  |  |_ Class1.java
|  |  |_ Class2.java
|  |_ package2/
|  |  |_ Class1.java
|  |  |_ Class2.java
```

When I [import the source code into Astah](https://astah.net/support/astah-pro/user-guide/java/#import), the files are imported correctly.

However, when I want to [auto generate](https://astah.net/support/astah-pro/user-guide/class-diagrams/) a diagram for the entire project, it just gets split up in packages like so:
[image]

Is there a way to completely generate a uml diagram with nested packages? Preferrably with Astah, if not then please link me a program that can do that.